# How do i scrape the content that pops up when i move my mouse over another content?

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, request

i am new to web scraping and i have been trying to scrape the text content that comes up when i hover my mouse on the **8g** located on the background image from this site: https://www.dietdoctor.com/recipes/sullivans-kedough-breakfast-pizza but all my effort with beautifulSoup is futile.
please how do i go about this.

Thanks in advance.
This is the link the image that describe where the mouse hover content is located:

[image]

i have tried these following codes suggested by @Andrrej kesely

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.dietdoctor.com/recipes/sullivans-kedough-breakfast-pizza'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
soup = BeautifulSoup(soup.select_one('.recipe-energy-mark-wrapper[data-js-popup]')['data-js-popup'], 'html.parser')

# print some data to screen:
for t in soup.select('title'):
    print(t.text)
```

but it keeps giving **TypeError:  'NoneType' object is not subscriptable**

Comment: Self-duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/62502097/5468463

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.dietdoctor.com/recipes/sullivans-kedough-breakfast-pizza'

response = requests.get(url)

# Takes the html source and feeds into BeautifulSoup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

# In the 'soup' object, we'll select the the first element with class ".recipe-energy-mark-wrapper"
# Within that element, the data is the value of the attribute 'data-js-popup'
jsPopup = soup.select_one('.recipe-energy-mark-wrapper')['data-js-popup']

# Normally you probably wouldn't need this part, but that value is stored as the html string
# that we are after, so we'll feed that string into BeautifulSoup to parse that html
soup = BeautifulSoup(jsPopup, 'html.parser')
print (soup.text, '\n')


for t in soup.select('title'):
    print(t.text)
```

Comment: The script he has in question works as it is, but he's getting Captcha page on first soup load. I cannot reproduce it on my side unfortunately.